# Any version of Open Mapping Theorem for Real Analytic Function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm studying analytic functions and wondering if there is any version of Open Mapping Theorem for real analytic functions.

In particular, let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a real analytic function. Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be an open subset. Is it true that $f(D)$ is also an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?
I have seen this kind of result for complex analytic functions but not sure if it also holds for real functions.

If this does not hold for *analytic* functions then which types of *real* functions can have this property?

I wd appreciate if someone can provide some references on this topic.

Thanks,

Comment: What about $f(x) = x^2$ on $(-1,1)$?

Comment: No, for all sorts of reasons: 1. things like $\cos x$ 2. The function $(x,y) \to (x,0)$ 3. Real analytic functions can have maximums

Comment: are you aware of any real functions from R^m to R^n that might have this property?